# Cannot connect to GCE slave via SSH as root

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, google-compute-engine

I have installed GCE plugin on Jenkins to provision nodes on demand for builds.
Nodes get provisioned as expected if runAs = [Jenkins] user is selected, but getting below error in agent logs when i want run build as [root] user. I went through https://github.com/jenkinsci/google-compute-engine-plugin/issues/69
and my java is in default path too.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
INFO: Authenticating as root
Aug 19, 2022 6:55:21 PM null
INFO: Connecting to <public IP> on port 22, with timeout 10000.
Aug 19, 2022 6:55:21 PM null
INFO: Connected via SSH.
Aug 19, 2022 6:55:21 PM null
WARNING: Authentication failed. Trying again...
Aug 19, 2022 6:55:36 PM null
WARNING: Authentication failed
Aug 19, 2022 6:55:36 PM null
WARNING: bootstrapresult failed
```

Comment: 1) Did you create a VPC Firewall rule allowing ingress traffic on port 22? 2) Once you solve the timeout issue, note that root logins are disabled in Google Cloud. You must modify the SSH server configuration to enable root logins.

Comment: John , thanks for response.
yes firewall is in-place..
with more debugging I find out that ownership of /root directory was set to different user for some reason, 
Doing 
chown -R root:root /root fixed my problem here.

Comment: How did the ownership of `/root` get modified?

Comment: We had changed, in pipeline we wanted to uninstall a package which was installed by root user. jenkins user was not having permissions do that. Paid price for that :P